# Discord.js. Cannot add permissions to slash commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Im trying to add permission to commands in such way, that only users with specific role can use it. At first im creating commands like its said in documentation.

Then Im trying to get each command and adding to them new permissions:

```js
await commands.forEach(command => {
    const permissions2 = [
        {
            id: guild.roles.everyone.id,
            type: 'ROLE',
            permission: false,
        }
    ];
    const permissions1 = [
        {
            id: botRole.id,
            type: 'ROLE',
            permission: true,
        },
    ];

    console.log(`Changing command ${command.id}`);
    command.permissions.add(permissions2);
    command.permissions.add(permissions1);
});
```

But whatever I do I get this error: `TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied permissions is not an Array of ApplicationCommandPermissionData.` 
Ive also tried running this code as shown in documentation but got same result:

```js
await commands.forEach(command => {
    ...
    console.log(`Changing command ${command.id}`);
    command.permissions.add({permissions2});
    command.permissions.add({permissions1});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing code to this helped:

```
const permissions2 = {
        id: guild.roles.everyone.id,
        type: 'ROLE',
        permission: false,
    };
    const permissions1 =  {
        id: botRole.id,
        type: 'ROLE',
        permission: true,
    };
    let commandsList = await guild.commands.fetch();
    await commandsList.forEach(slashCommand => {
        console.log(`Changing command ${slashCommand.id}`);
        //set the permissions for each slashCommand
        guild.commands.permissions.add({
            command: slashCommand.id,
            permissions: [permissions1, permissions2]
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can use the forEach loop like you did.

[`commands.permissions#set`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager?scrollTo=set) consists of an object with the id of the command you want to edit, and an array with the permissions.

So you would have to rewrite your code to this:

```js
//create the permissions objects
const permissions2 = {
  id: guild.roles.everyone.id,
  type: 'ROLE',
  permission: false,
};
const permissions1 =  {
  id: botRole.id,
  type: 'ROLE',
  permission: true,
};


//loop through all the slashCommands
await commands.forEach(slashCommand => {
    console.log(`Changing command ${slashCommand.id}`);

    //set the permissions for each slashCommand
    client.application.commands.permissions.set({command: slashCommand.id, permissions: [permissions1, permissions2]});
});
```

Read more about setting permissions for slashCommands [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager)

Comment: guild.commands is a [GuildApplicationCommandManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildApplicationCommandManager), it doesnt allow to use forEach.
But changing brackets helped, thank you

Comment: @AlexanderShashkov I changed my answer. It should work now like I showed it here too.

Comment: For some reason, it still gives me TypeError: `client.application.commands.forEach is not a function`. Documentation says that application.commands is ApplicationCommandManager

Comment: @AlexanderShashkov since I cant test the code myself, I assume that `commands.forEach` like you have should work fine acutally. Sorry for the inconvenience